# Is there a perferred tag to use for onclick events in menus (for accessibility)

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I am wondering if there is an ideal html tag to use for menus (such as navigation and context menus) when handling onclick events that fire api calls.

Obviously anchor tags are the way to go for links, but when it is onclick="apiCall();" is there a perferred tag? And if there is not should I give it an aria-role?

Currently what I am doing is:

```
<a
  aria-role="button"
  onclick="() => apiCall(props);"
  class="block"
>
  Add to Sticker Print Queue
</a>
```

(the above example was modified from react code)

I notice on some websites people use
`<a href="javascript:void(0)">Text </a>` as can be seen in this post:  [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/which-href-value-should-i-use-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

However, the majority of answers in the above talk about scalability, not accessibility.

Comment: The common approach seems to be using anchor elements when clicking will cause a navigation to a new location, whereas button elements are typically used to change/update the content of the current page.

Comment: Sometimes an api call doesn't update information on the page, it could just be a simple post request where the information isn't being displayed on the page. But I do agree with what you are saying, that was my main reason in using aria-role="button"

Comment: Golden rule - if the URL changes it is an anchor, otherwise it is a button. So even if you process something first or are using AJAX if the location changes it is an anchor. If the location stays the same it is a button. There are some very rare edge cases (if you have a url for a no JS fallback) but if you follow that rule you are very unlikely to get it wrong. `javascript:void(0)` is a relic of HTML4 days that just won't go away. Maybe see if https://dev.to/inhuofficial/they-just-won-t-learn-a-button-is-a-lt-button-gt-accessibility-rants-k1b helps with clarity.